# Include special chars in regex search

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following function in js:

```
function validWord(v) {
    return /^\w+(\'\w+)?(\s\w+(\'\w+)?)*?(\s*)?$/.test(v);
}
```

What it does it finds any string that contain [a-zA-Z0-9_].
What I want is to add . / and $ sign to the regex.
How do I do modify the fucntion?

I tried:

```
^\w+(\'\w+\.\$\/)?(\s\w+(\'\w+)?)*?(\s*)?$
```

but not working.

PS.  Please explain what the modified code will do, since I am very bad at regex.

Comment: can't write this in a comment ... see https://regex101.com/r/8ZUujF/1/ to see what you're doing

Comment: @JaromandaX alredy tried bro :)

Comment: so, you don't understand what that is telling you? your first capturing group is the sequence `'` followed by 1 or more `\w` followed by `.$` followed by \ ... where as I think you want to add .$\ to the \w ? so [\w\.$\\\]+ ? (backslashes are killing me here) - i.e. `[]` brackets?

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you that helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/^[\w\.$/]+(\'\w+)?(\s\w+(\'\w+)?)*?(\s*)?$` is the answer I was looking for.